# JavaScript Chrome vs IE

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have very simple JavaScript code that copies values from one form into another. It works perfectly in Chrome, but in IE not everything is being copied. The "state field" would not copy. The state field is actually "select" field. Here is the function:

```
function FillMemberInfo(f){

      if(f.chkMemberInfo.checked == true) {
        f.member_firstname1.value = f.client_first_name.value;
        f.member_lastname1.value = f.client_last_name.value;
        f.member_address1.value = f.client_address.value;
        f.member_city1.value = f.client_city.value;
        f.member_state1.value = f.client_state.value;
        f.member_zip1.value = f.client_zip.value;
      } else {
        f.member_firstname1.value = "";
        f.member_lastname1.value = "";
        f.member_address1.value = "";
        f.member_city1.value = "";
        f.member_state1.value = "";
        f.member_zip1.value = "";

      }
    }
```

Comment: Try copying `.selectedIndex` instead of `.value`

Comment: @Pointy D'oh. Didn't think of that. Although to be fair that relies on the `<select>`s being absolutely identical. This might not always be the case, especially if the first has a "Select one..." option or something.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol yes that's true; I kind-of assumed that'd be the case but it may not be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly set `.value` on a `<select>` unless the browser is clever enough to do that.

Try something like this:

```
function setSelectValue(sel,val) {
    var opts = sel.options, l = opts.length, i;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
        if( opts[i].value == val) {
            sel.selectedIndex = i;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
setSelectValue(f.member_state1, f.client_state.value);
```

It should be noted that still older browsers don't support *reading* `.value` from a `<select>`, and you should ideally do:

```
f.client_state.options[f.client_state.selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: Why not just copy `selectedIndex` (assuming the lists of options are the same) ?

Comment: @dystroy See my reply to Pointy's comment on the question.

Comment: Maybe a first paragraph suggesting to copy selectedIndex *if* the lists are identical would be in order, then.